# Resizing Button In HTML/CSS Would Not Work As Expected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

I want to resize the button and expand it a bit more so the text fills in properly.

This is the HTML and CSS of my button:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta:700");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body1 {
  font-family: "Mukta", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #f3f8fa;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
}
button.learn-more {
  width: 12rem;
  height: auto;
}
button.learn-more .circle {
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  position: relative;
  right: 25px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  background: #282936;
  border-radius: 1.625rem;
}
button.learn-more .circle .icon {
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
}
button.learn-more .circle .icon.arrow {
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  left: 0.625rem;
  width: 1.125rem;
  height: 0.125rem;
  background: none;
}
button.learn-more .circle .icon.arrow::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -0.25rem;
  right: 0.0625rem;
  width: 0.625rem;
  height: 0.625rem;
  border-top: 0.125rem solid #fff;
  border-right: 0.125rem solid #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
button.learn-more .button-text {
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0.75rem 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 1.85rem;
  color: #282936;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.6;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
button:hover .circle {
  width: 125%;
}
button:hover .circle .icon.arrow {
  background: #fff;
  transform: translate(1rem, 0);
}
button:hover .button-text {
  color: #fff;
}

@supports (display: grid) {
  body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 0.625rem;
    grid-template-areas: ". main main ." ". main main .";
  }

  #yes {
    grid-area: main;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
  }
}
```

```html
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/button.css" />
   

<div id="yes">
  <button class="learn-more">
    <span class="circle">
      <span class="icon arrow"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="button-text">Check Out My Blogs!</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

After you run the above code, you can see it outputs the text in different lines, but I want the whole text to be in the same line.

Expected Output:

[This should be my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0Hyj.png)

Basically, what happened was that I wanted to include the HTML and CSS of the button to another IDE which has my main project. The CSS of the button however was overriding/colliding with the CSS of my main project, so I renamed the `body {` in the CSS of the button to `body1 {` and now it produces the text on a different line. But if you change body1 to just body, it fixes it. But I do not want that since `body {` is located in the main CSS file of my project and will mix up with the CSS of the button, so I renamed it to `body1 }`. Is there any way to get the expected output I showed above with a picture by changing any of the CSS elements?

Comment: Increase the button width from the `12rem` it's currently set to...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as answer what @Rory said in the comment.

Changed the width of the class `button.learn-more` to  16rem:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta:700");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body1 {
  font-family: "Mukta", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #f3f8fa;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
}
button.learn-more {
  width: 16rem;
  height: auto;
}
button.learn-more .circle {
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  position: relative;
  right: 25px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  background: #282936;
  border-radius: 1.625rem;
}
button.learn-more .circle .icon {
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
}
button.learn-more .circle .icon.arrow {
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  left: 0.625rem;
  width: 1.125rem;
  height: 0.125rem;
  background: none;
}
button.learn-more .circle .icon.arrow::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -0.25rem;
  right: 0.0625rem;
  width: 0.625rem;
  height: 0.625rem;
  border-top: 0.125rem solid #fff;
  border-right: 0.125rem solid #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
button.learn-more .button-text {
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0.75rem 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 1.85rem;
  color: #282936;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.6;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
button:hover .circle {
  width: 125%;
}
button:hover .circle .icon.arrow {
  background: #fff;
  transform: translate(1rem, 0);
}
button:hover .button-text {
  color: #fff;
}

@supports (display: grid) {
  body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 0.625rem;
    grid-template-areas: ". main main ." ". main main .";
  }

  #yes {
    grid-area: main;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
  }
}
```

```html
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/button.css" />
   

<div id="yes">
  <button class="learn-more">
    <span class="circle">
      <span class="icon arrow"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="button-text">Check Out My Blogs!</span>
  </button>
</div>
```